# How to install "arm" package in R/Rstudio for downloading it directly and not from the Packages ->Install interface?

Tags: r, download, package

I'd like to install the "arm" package in RStuio but I don't have the right to install it via the Packages ->Install interface. I have access to install it via an offline version of the package. Were I can find a downloadable installer for this package?

Many thanks

Comment: What operating system are you using? You can download a binary relevant to your platform http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arm/index.html and install locally.

Comment: @jdharrison Windows. I've tried it just before posting my question. There is no installer there. Wat do you mean by instal locally ? As you can see I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Download the windows zip and `install.packages('zipPath', repos = NULL)` where `'zipPath'` is the path to the downloaded zip.

Comment: @jdharrison Do you mean to type it in the command line interface? Could you please develop your answer? Thanks